# Php stops running (?) when calling reports->batchGet in Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Im using the basic testing code provided by google [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) with the necessary replacements of keys and such. The problem that I'm having is that nothing will run after `$analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );` runs. To make it more strange, it also doesn't give any sort of error message in the error logs or the console.

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
print_r($analytics);
$response = getReport($analytics);
print_r("here");
print_r($response);
printResults($response);
print_r("here");


/**
 * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 *
 * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 */
function initializeAnalytics()
{

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  return $analytics;
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "view id is here";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();

  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  print_r($body);
  $temp = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
  print_r("here3");

  return $temp;
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Im running this on XAMPP on a manjaro install if that helps at all.

Theoretically it should return some sort of JSON string I think? But regardless, the code should not just stop running.

My best guess is that something is hung up inside the batchGet function but I don't know what it would be or how to go about fixing that.

Comment: Start by filing a bug report maybe on Github?

Comment: You think its a bug on their end @emix ? I'm pretty new at this so I was assuming that I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason XAMPP was not showing any error message even when there was one. When I ran with just `php` in command line, it showed an error message like I would expect (it had to do with some permissions).